# Kotlin: How to call setters and getters from java class?

Tags: java, kotlin

So I have multiple textFields in my java class which I want to be able to get from my kotlin class to get its text and then store into a database. However, I have checked multiple sites and watched many videos, but none explicitly mention how to get a variable.

Below is my java class, how can I access and get the information inputted into these fields from a Kotlin class?

```
TextField projectName = new TextField();
TextField teamName = new TextField();
TextField mainTaskName = new TextField();
TextField additionalTask = new TextField();
ComboBox teamSelection = new ComboBox();
ComboBox supportSelection = new ComboBox();


public TextField getProjectName() {
    return projectName;
}

public TextField getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}

public ComboBox getTeamSelection() {
    return teamSelection;
}

public ComboBox getSupportSelection() {
    return supportSelection;
}

public TextField getMainTaskName() {
    return mainTaskName;
}

public TextField getAdditionalTask() {
    return additionalTask;
}
```

Comment: Please read this page and it will tell you everything. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html

Answer (score 2):

Methods that follow the Java conventions for getters and setters (no-argument methods with names starting with get and single-argument methods with names starting with set) are represented as properties in Kotlin.

Call `yourClassInstance.projectName` for example.

Source: [Calling Java from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html)

Comment: I try following the page but I still don't understand, this is my first time learning Kotlin, so please do forgive me if this is self explanatory, I tried " val info = projectInformation.getProjectName() " but I get an error?

Comment: Remove the ``get`` from your code and switch to camel case: ``val info = projectInformation.projectName``

Comment: I did exactly this and I get the following error = "Kotlin: Unresolved reference: ProjectName ", however if I make the variables static it works, but doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of setters and getters?

Comment: projectName with the first p in lowercase... use camelCase not UpperCase

Comment: Yeah I have done this aswell, " val info = projectInformation.projectName ", but it still gives me an error of "Kotlin: Unresolved reference: projectName", however it works when I make my projectName a static TextField Variable, but I don't understand why it needs to be static, this just defeats the whole purpose of setters and getters right?

Comment: Hmmmm can you try making the projectName variable ``private``? You may be having visibility conflicts since the TextFields are package-visible. I'm not sure on that though. If you need more help past this point, please move the discussion to a chat as suggested.

Comment: Tried that aswell, still did not work, thanks for the help!